# Ho to add a Plotly graph to a Bokeh/Panel Server

Tags: plotly, panel, bokeh

I looked at the Pyviz [documentation](http://pyviz.org/) and it states that with Panel it is possible to plot visuals from several libraries including Plotly. I cannot find any example on how to do this.

This is an example of Plotly visual I'd like to have in a Panel server:

import plotly.plotly as py

```
data = dict(
    type='sankey',
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(
        color = "black",
        width = 0.5
      ),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
      color = ["blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue", "blue"]
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0,1,0,2,3,3],
      target = [2,3,3,4,4,5],
      value = [8,4,2,8,4,2]
  ))

layout =  dict(
    title = "Basic Sankey Diagram",
    font = dict(
      size = 10
    )
)

fig = dict(data=[data], layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, validate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second example on the homepage at panel.pyviz.org ([Gapminders](https://anaconda.org/jbednar/panel_gapminders/notebook)) includes a plotly graph.